# How to Run a Whole site From index.php

Tags: php, mysql, url, web

I have noticed that in a couple of sites they can run the whole site from just the index.php, I also noticed the same effect in phpmyadmin to some extent.

An example of a site that does this is [Try Open School](http://tryopenschool.com/), it is a demo site, and you can log in with (admin as password and admin as username, or teacher, teacher, or student, student). If you notice all that changes about the `URL` is the `Query String`.

I looked through the site and all I can Image is a whole lot of codes on just one page, But I do not think this is the case. I tried mine and I did something like this..

```
<?php
    if($_GET['ref'] == 'home')
   {
     require_once("home.php");

   }
   elseif($_GET['ref'] == 'profile')
   {
       require_once("profile.php");

   } 
?>
```

I used the `URL Query String` to make reference to the different pages and to make other logical decisions.

I did a whole lot of this on the page, and the page contained several hundreds of `if else statements`. I do not know if I am doing what they did on their site.
I love the concept and would like to implement that kind of stuff on my own site.

I would appreciate all help on how to go about this. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If $_GET['ref'] is the only parameter for selecting page. a php switch, would probably be a better solution.

If you want to get fewer lines of code in your index file, you could put the switch in a separete php file!

Like this (index.php)

```
<?php

 echo "<div id=header>Someinput</div>
 <div id=menu>Some menu input</div>
 <div id=site>";

      require("switch.php");

 echo "</div>
 <div id=footer>Some footer input</div>";
 ?>
```

Then (switch.php):

```
<?php

    switch($_GET['ref']){
         case "page1":
              include("page1.php");
              break 1;

         case "page2":
              include("page2.php");
              break 1;
         default:
              include("404.php");
    }
?>
```

Comment: thats an other question. If you put all your code in one file, that file will be a pain in the *** to work with, personally i preffer smaller, well organized files. But that doesn't mean you can't run them all from index.php. I would guess that doesn't matter that much (i could be wrong though)